# Find the differential equation of family of circles each of which touch the lines $ y=x $ and $y=-x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, circles

A family of circle has $3$ arbitrary constants if I write it as $x^2+y^2+2fx+2gy+h=0$. So since I have two conditions I can reduce this to an equation with 1 arbitrary constant. Then I will get a first order ODE.  But how do I do this? That is change the equation to one with only one arbitrary constant. If I substitute $y=x$ and $y=-x$ then subtracting the two easily yields $g=0$. But it doesn't tell me anything about f and h. What can I do for that? 
Please let me know if what I'm thinking is correct.
Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: You can say more, you can say that the circle equation is $(x-\sqrt2 c)+y^2=c^2$. Take the derivative of that and eliminate $c$.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you for the comment sir.  How did you arrive at that equation?

Comment: @LutzL I can just substitute $y=x$ and $y=-x$ in the original circle equation and then add the respective results to arrive at the form you're talking about right?

Comment: I think you make a mistake in the circle equation.  Your circle **always** passes through the origin!

Comment: The $h$ should be somewhere else!

Comment: @Qwerty Yes you're correct that when I substitute the conditions given,  the $xy$ vanishes.  Initially I mentioned the equation of any arbitrary circle.

Comment: Your equation of **any arbitrary circle** is wrong!

Comment: @Qwerty oops.  I corrected it.

Comment: As you are new to this site , let me tell you, Unless **you** show **your** work,what you have tried, no one will bother to solve your problem. People here are to help, not spoonfeed. You show your work and people will tell you what is right and what is wrong!

Comment: @Qwerty But I don't know how to find the equation of such a circle. I just want to know that.  I am able to eliminate one constant but I still can't find a  way to eliminate one more.

Comment: If you put $y=x$ you will get a quadratic in $x$ whose $b^2=4ac$ (conventions) .you will get those points where the circle touches the line $y=x$

Comment: That does eliminate one more constant but why is the discriminant 0? Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions.

Comment: There are the *two* following sets with the same envelopes. Differentiate and eliminate the constants $(u,v)$ in either case.In each case $ g=0;\, f = \sqrt{2 h}; \quad f=0;\, g = \sqrt{2 h}; $ This is found correctly  by putting $x \pm y = 0 $ and setting discriminant to zero as it is a double root.

$$ x^2 + ( y - u \sqrt 2 )^2 = u^2,\quad y^2 + ( x- v \sqrt 2 )^2 = v^2,\quad $$

Comment: @Narasimham what is the double root?

Comment: Ok, ok,  shall include all this into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To derive the circle equation beginning from your general circle form:

$$ x^2+y^2 + 2 f x + 2 g y + h = 0 \tag {1} $$

Put $x= +y$ and simplify, you get

$$ 2 x^2 + (2 f+2 g)x +h =0 , \quad   x^2+ (f+ g) x + h/2 =0 \tag{2}$$

Discriminant should vanish when we have tangency (but not secancy :), which cuts at two points like the situation at H).

[[image: Circles touching <span class=]$ x^2=y^2$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51fvl.png)

$$ (f+g)^2 = 4 * h/2 = 2 h  \tag{3} $$

Similarly for  $ x= -y $ we have

$$ (f-g)^2 = 4 * h/2 = 2 h \tag{4} $$

Solving (3),(4)

$$ g=0,\, f = \sqrt {2 h} = \sqrt {2} u  \tag {5} $$

Plug back into  (0) and re-write

$$ x^2 + y^2 - 2 u\sqrt 2 + u^2 =0 \tag{6} $$

$$ ( y - \sqrt 2 \,u)^2 +x^2 = u^2 \tag{7}$$

Similarly for the other set of circles centered on x-axis.

There are these two sets we see with the same tangency loci $ x= \pm y$  also called *envelopes*, with full symmetry about both axes of $x$ and $y$. So change sign before $\pm$ symbol is admissible.

$$x^2+(y−u √2)^2=u^2,x^2+(y−v √2)^2=v^2 \tag{8} $$

Differentiate and eliminate the constants $(u,v)$ in either case. The latter part I leave it to you, others also indicated it in their answers.

EDIT1:

Radius of circle is u, power $u^2$
$$x^2 +(y-\sqrt 2 u)^2= u^2 $$
Differentiate once and 
cancel 2
$$ x+y'(y-\sqrt 2 u) =0 $$
Differentiate once again to obtain second order DE 
$$ 1 +(y-\sqrt 2 u) y^{''}+y'^2 =0 $$

$$ y +\frac{1+y'^2}{y''}= \sqrt2 u $$

To remove RHS third time differentiate and simplify

$$ y' + \frac{y''(2 y'y'') -(1+y'^2) y'''}{y''^2} =0 $$

$$ y'''= \frac{ 3 y'y''^2}{1+y'^2}$$

Comment: The question says it touches the circle.  That means they're tangent to the circle.  Wow I missed that.  This is what I was struggling with.  Thanks for the visual aid.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The circle equation is
$$
    (x-M_x)^2 +(y-M_y)^2=R^2
$$
with tangent equation at some point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the circle 
$$
(x_0-M_x)(x-x_0)+(y_0-M_y)(y-y_0)=0
$$
One of the tangents shall be $y=x$, thus also $y_0=x_0$inserting and comparing linear and constant coefficients one finds
$$
(x_0-M_x)+(x_0-M_y)=0
$$
which identifies the coordinates of the tangency point as $x_0=y_0=\frac12(M_x+M_y)$ which in turn requires for the circle equation
$$
(M_y-M_x)^2=2R^2
$$

From the other tangent $y=-x$ one finds similarly
$$
(x_0-M_x)+(x_0+M_y)=0\iff x_0=-y_0=\frac12(M_x-M_y)\\\implies (M_x+M_y)^2=2R^2
$$
For the center points one gets thus the $4$ solutions $M_y=0$, $M_x=\pm\sqrt2 R$ and $M_x=0$, $M_y=\pm\sqrt2 R$.

---

Take the first case and compute the $x$ derivative of the circle equation
$$
2(x-\sqrt2 R)+2y(x)y'(x)=0
$$
and insert in the original circle equation eliminating $R$,
$$
(yy')^2+y^2=\frac12(x+yy')^2\iff (yy'-x)^2 +2y^2-2x^2=0
$$

Comment: Why will the tangent be y=x?

Comment: Why are both the lines tangent to the circle? It's not mentioned.

Comment: You got two linear equations, the tangent equation and the diagonal line. Now just identify coefficients so that they become equivalent. After that they are by construction tangent to the circle.

Comment: I really don't understand the part where you said that the given two lines are tangent to the circle. For instance why can't we have that the line cuts the circle at two points?

Comment: Because they are equated to tangent equations. $F(x,y)=0$ has tangent equations $F_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+F_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)=0$. For the line $y=x$ to be among them one needs apart from $F(x_0,x_0)=0$ also $[F_x(x_0,x_0)+F_y(x_0,x_0)](x-x_0)=0$.